# Go over an object, and return a component to each attribute in the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi everyone I'm new to react, I built component - I have a state of user preferences - and I do go over all preferences, and return the rating he gave to each preference - with the help of mui - I have been trying for several hours to do this, I can not.

This is the code I wrote, it runs but I do not get the component back, I do not understand why.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
// MUI stuff
import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';
// Icons
import ListIcon from '@material-ui/icons/List';


class Profile extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = 
    {preferences: {
      html: "5",
      react: "4",
      css: "4",
      angular: "3",
}};
  }

  render() {
    let profilePreferences = {preferences && (
                <Fragment>
                  <ListIcon color="primary" />
                  <hr />
                  {
                    Object.keys(preferences).map(prefer => {<Rating name={prefer} defaultValue={parseInt(preferences[prefer], base)} precision={1} readOnly/>}) 
                  }
                  
                  <hr />
                </Fragment>
              )}
    return profilePreferences ;
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

I think the problem is very small, but I can not find it, I just want to go over my object and for each feature, return a "rating" component of "materialUi".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem of your code was that you didn't use `this.state.preferences`. The second problem was you are confused about the usage of `{}` and `()` parentheses in JS. The third point - Do not forget to print key when you output a list of elements.

I have edited your code. Here is [a working example on codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-worker-0vl9w?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `preferences` is undefined. You need to get it from `this.state`.

```
render() {
    const { preferences } = this.state; // <------ Add this line
    let profilePreferences = {preferences && (
                <Fragment>
                  <ListIcon color="primary" />
                  <hr />
                  {
                    Object.keys(preferences).map(prefer => (<Rating name={prefer} defaultValue={parseInt(preferences[prefer], base)} precision={1} readOnly/>)) 
                  }
                  
                  <hr />
                </Fragment>
              )}
    return profilePreferences ;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it does not work, I do not understand why, I tried to fix the code like you said, but the components of "rating" do not come.

Comment: I see. I updated answer so check again. Use `()` instead of `{}`. If you are using `{}`, then you have to return component inside `{}` block.

Comment: Works great !!! Thank you very much, can you tell me what you changed? I got entangled with it for hours !!